# Godot Android - How to properly save game data on application exit?

Tags: android, godot

I am creating a Godot Android game and i have a problem; i can't automatically save data when user focuses out of the application. Whether user presses the back button or home button, i need to run some code to save data. In apps that i create with Android Studio, i can easily override the methods `onPause()` and `onStop()`, that works as expected: when app goes to background it still runs the code in these methods. But using Godot's notification system, catching the notifications `NOTIFICATION_APP_PAUSED` and `NOTIFICATION_WM_FOCUS_OUT` both don't work.

I have considered of creating an android plugin and override lifecycle methods, but its too limited because i can't call my game functions from there.

So is there a viable solution for automatically saving on exit?